# Sanitizing like mysqli::real_escape_string in Magento2

Tags: magento2, product, import

Sanitizing like mysqli::real_escape_string in Magento2..

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_categories(col1, col2, col3) VALUES ('val1', 'val2', 'val3')";
$connection->query($sql);
```

Comment: Your question is not clear to me? Can you explain more details?

Comment: I am getting Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax..

Comment: I need to escape string before insert..

Answer (score 0):

As per your question ,You need to use function mysqli_real_escape_string for every values which are you inserting in your query.

```
$val1 = mysql_real_escape_string($val1);
$val2 = mysql_real_escape_string($val2);
$val3 = mysql_real_escape_string($val3);

$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_categories(col1, col2, col3) VALUES ($val1, $val2, $val3)";
$connection->query($sql);
```